# HTML remove scrollbar background in div/set background transparency

Tags: html, css

I have a div that contains a large amount of text. I have set overflow:auto; and need to keep it that way. The scrollbar however, has a white background - is there a way to get rid of this by removing its background and/or setting transparency. 
Thanks.

Comment: There is [no cross-browser](http://support.mozilla.com/nl/questions/775958) solution to force the browser's scrollbars to have a specific color. If you want to hide the scrollbars, while getting the `overflow:auto` "behaviour", use `overflow:hidden`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no cross-browser css-only solution. Only IE supports it with native css (like in [Shawn Steward's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931205/html-remove-scrollbar-background-in-div-set-background-transparency#answer-7931238)).

Your only chance is to mimick native scrollbars with JavaScript. Here is a [overview of some jQuery-plugins](http://www.net-kit.com/jquery-custom-scrollbar-plugins/).

Answer (score 0):

You can set CSS on your scrollbar styles like such:

(IE ONLY)

```
<style type="text/css">
.overflowDiv { 
scrollbar-face-color : #FF0000; 
scrollbar-highlight-color : #FF6666; 
scrollbar-3dlight-color : #FF9999;
scrollbar-darkshadow-color : #660000; 
scrollbar-arrow-color : #FFCCCC; 
scrollbar-shadow-color : #FF0000; 
scrollbar-track-color: #330000
} 
</style>
```

Comment: is this cross browser, or just for IE?

Comment: Yeah, thats what i thought. Are there any solutions not for cross browsers

Comment: Nope other browsers won't allow you to modify scrollbars because they're part of the application.  The only other thing I could think of would be to absolute position a semi-transparent overlay on top of the scrollbar to change how it may look but then you may not be able to use it...

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the text in a "textarea" tag and then style it up, making sure to include:

```
textarea { overflow: auto; }
```

somewhere in the style sheet?